# Is there a limit to Pages in Pages Module?

Tags: pages

I've been working on moving a ton of content around on a large University site.  I'm suddenly encountering a problem where the Pages module gets zeroed out. Pages start breaking all over the site, and when I go to the Pages Module, there are no entries in the listing.

Is there a limit to the number of pages I can put in the pages module?  Could this be a different issue?

I also notice that the pages aren't nested properly (at least how I would think they would be nested) in the pages module.  Example:

```
+foo
++foo/bar
++superman
```

Or worse:

```
+superman
++foo
++foo/bar
```

When foo has nothing to do with Superman, at all.  Am I not reading the pages nested output right?  Is something other than URI segments driving that nesting?

EE 2.9.2 , Pages 2.2

Thanks!

Comment: How many pages are we talking about?

Comment: I see a little over 880 in the listing on the Add-Ons -> Modules -> Pages CP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a hard "## number of pages is too many" answer - but  880 is certainly pushing the Pages Module way past what it was designed for.  See my writeup on the [history of the pages module.](http://www.train-ee.com/courseware/free-tutorials/comments/pages-module-1-an-introduction-and-history)

The Pages Module wasn't developed to be the basis of building the nav for an entire site and you are seeing the results of trying to do so.

Comment: I inherited this site, and I'm trying to improve it.  The site is a University site with multiple departments/units, who all are/have what are functionally mini-sites inside the master site.  Every channel entry is pretty much representing a separate page on the site, and the URL and template are set using the pages module.  What I'm doing now is consolidating content into channels that make sense for users, and consolidating all the templates down to a master template using stash partials. I'd love a better design pattern for what I'm doing, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: That's the thing with EE - it's so flexible there are usually a multiple ways of doing things. Some good, some not so much.  University sites seem to be their own monster between a complex IA and designers/builders that come and go with the changing academic years.  It seems like the people responsible for setting the development direction rarely stick around long enough to suffer the consequences of their decisions..;)

Comment: I think you're generally on the right track. Channels should be modeled around content types and user groups. Personally I'd stick with native template layouts and snippets over Stash - but it's just my preference to stay 1st party as much as possible. Navigation is one spot I'd probably look to use a 3rd party tool like Taxonomy.

Comment: You've been generally reassuring, and I thank you!  But I still wonder what's up with the Pages module dumping itself, and showing wrong nesting while it's actually populated.  Guess I can ask Ellislab, if my school bought any support...